# Grayish line appearing around background image of a div

Tags: html, css

I have a single div that's 100% of the width and height of the page.

I've set the background of the div to an animated gif and made the height of the background change with the div's height (which is 100% the height of the page).  The background image repeats horizontally and is positioned at the bottom of the page.

---

#### HTML / CSS

Run this snippet in Chrome, make it full-screen and then resize the window until the line appears.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.bottomAnim {
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #2851A6 url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/spmUM.gif") left repeat-x;
  background-size: auto 65%;
  background-position: bottom;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottomAnim"></div>
```

---

The problem is that a gray, horizontal thin line appears on top of the background image.  The background of the page is the same color as the top of the image, so I don't know where the line is coming from.  When I make the browser's (Google Chrome) height very short, the line disappears. This problem doesn't occur on Safari.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhoa0.jpg]

As can be seen in the screenshot above, the repeating background image is positioned at the bottom.  There is are no vertical liens between every repeated image but there is one horizontal line that goes across all of them.  I've checked the image and the line is not there, it is produced by the browser.  How do I get rid of this line?  I've looked at other posts on this but none of the fixes work.

Here's the background image:

[image: Background image]

Comment: Have you used the developer tools (page inspector)?

Comment: Yes, nothing seems to be wrong.

Comment: Can you provide the image that you are using? Hard to fix without recreating it :)

Comment: Recut the image, cutout 1 or more pixels from the top.

Comment: And use i.e. `Signalcitycropped.gif?001` to force to reload it.

Comment: @Pangloss I already tried cutting out the top of the image and that didn't work.  I also tried you're fix and added ?001 and still the line appears.

Comment: @misterManSam I edited my post and added the image I used for the background at the bottom

Comment: Is there a way you can add a link to the page in which you're using it? I'd like to take a look.

Comment: Is there no other markup? Ie. is this just a truncated StackOverflow-friendly version? It could be that it's another element altogether that's creating that line.

Comment: I re-created the problem. It is caused by the resize done by `background-size` and I've seen this before. If you remove it the line no longer appears. [Here is an example](http://jsbin.com/coheqo/edit?css,output). A work around would be to not scale the image, not very helpful I know!

Comment: @misterManSam Thanks for adding the "run code snippet" functionality.  In regards to the resizing, that would be a problem especially because I want the image to be at the bottom of the div and repeat horizontally.  If I can't resize it, it would cover the whole screen in smaller windows and devices.  I'm going to add text to the area above the image.  Is there any other solution other than not scaling the image?

Comment: Also, the line also disappears if I make the browser window's width very narrow.

Answer (score 1):

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.bottomAnim {
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #2851A6 url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/spmUM.gif") left repeat-x;
  background-size: auto;
  background-position: bottom;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottomAnim"></div>
```

Use this

```
  background-size: auto;
```

instead of

```
  background-size: auto 65%;
```

Comment: The line still remains.

Comment: I think it might be my 2800 by 1800 screen resolution, I'll check on other computers.  I'm using chrome 43.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

### `@media` workaround

This bug only appears to occur with larger viewport heights. Luckily it is not as critical to scale the image down after a certain height. With that in mind we can use `@media` queries to apply the `background-size` scaling only when the viewports height is under a certain size:

```
@media (max-height: 700px) {
  .bottomAnim {
    background-size: auto 65%;
  }
}
```

#### Working Example

[As a jsBin as well](http://jsbin.com/coheqo/edit?html,css,output)

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.bottomAnim {
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #2851A6 url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/spmUM.gif") left repeat-x;
  background-position: bottom;
  z-index: 1000;
}
@media (max-height: 700px) {
  .bottomAnim {
    background-size: auto 65%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bottomAnim"></div>
```

Comment: I'm using a 15" MacBook pro which has a height of 2800 pixels.  So, that might be the problem.  I'll check on other computers as well and see how it looks.  If this problem is only replicated on higher resolution viewports then it's okay.  Thank you for the help!